# When do you say "near ID" / "far ID" when using RTMFP in ActionScript 3?

Tags: terminology, flash, actionscript

I've been using RTMFP streaming for around a year in ActionScript 3, and I pretty much know the difference between a near ID and far ID.  The near ID is your peer ID, and the far ID is the other guy's peer ID.

The problem I'm having is that, to my knowledge, choosing whether to use one term or the other in a given sentence is a little like choosing whether to say "go" or "come".  In English, "go" and "come" have opposite meanings, but ironically, they can still be used almost interchangeably.  It's because whether you're going or coming is so heavily dependent on perspective, as opposed to anything concrete.

Is the choice of words between "near ID" and "far ID" just as ambiguous, or is there some sort of method to the madness?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is completely based on perspective: whether you're working from the perspective of a client or the server. I don't think of this as ambiguous, but it can be confusing if you're not clear on your perspective.

For reference, the [Flash Media Server 4.5 documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7ec3SSASLR.html#WS9f32e2dde83ae1f7-5aa1e574126fc38a5eb-8000) states:

> Client.farID
>
> A String identifying the RTMFP identity of the client. This property has the same value as the ActionScript 3.0 NetConnection.nearID property.
>
> Client.nearID
>
> A String indicating the RTMFP identity of the server to which the client is connected. This property has the same value as the ActionScript 3.0 NetConnection.farID property.

Comment: I was just able to start looking at this this morning.  It looks like it may take me a little while to fully grasp.  I actually wasn't even thinking about client vs. server, until you mentioned it, but you've kind of me more aware of that sort of thing.  I had been thinking though about client 1 vs. client 2, and speaking from kind of a third or semi-third party perspective.  Thanks.